# JAVAFX : TableModel : Edit : How to know value type (Which type of value i.e String,integer,or date) hold by Jtable cell(column wise)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

can any one  Tell me how to track Jtable row and column value types if i go through the table model each column.

```
enter code here
for (int i = 1 ; i < JTableHeaderCheckBox.table.getRowCount(); i++)
      {
        bfw.newLine();
        for(int j = 1 ; j < JTableHeaderCheckBox.table.getColumnCount();j++)
        {
          bfw.write((String)(JTableHeaderCheckBox.table.getValueAt(i,j)));

          bfw.write("\t");
        }
      }
      bfw.close();
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JTable.getModel().getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
```

Comment: 1+ for the `getColumnClass()` method, but you should use the getColumnClass() method of the JTable, not the TableModel because the columns could be reordered.

Comment: @ alex  actually  i have Jtable i want to print jtable in txt file table format  while print the column some column has long so it fire error long not convert into string.....so how i track weather column is boolean ,,int,long before print in file

Comment: @MohasinMujawar Just check for null and print empty value; for all other stuff pring its `toString()`. This should be sufficient.

Comment: This also assumes that the table model has been set up correctly to report the actual class type and, in the case of DefaultTableModel, the actually data is the right type (and not just all String's)